when working with attorneys, how are revisions typically done?
So after each draft, the attorney sends me a word document.
In my revisions, I create a new word document where I reference the sections that I think needs to be changed.
But I am wondering if this is standard or is this inefficient?
I just discovered that MS word has a diff viewer that can compare different documents.
So I am wonder if it is more efficient to just create a copy of the draft and then modify the copy directly, so that the attorney can use the diff viewer to see the changes that I made?

Word’s “Track Changes” mode works great for this.

When using MS Word, typically we used Comments and Track Changes. Track Changes is especially nice in that it communicates the desired edit in a way that the attorney can either accept or reject the proposed change easily and in context.

Either can work but it may be that the idea behind your change is the relevant information rather than your proposed changed wording.
Adding comments to the document is another approach - it might be another MS Word feature you could learn about.

Comments for sure. Also “ Track Changes”. Word has nice features for collaboration.
